# Undefined variable php notice workaround?

Tags: php

I just turned on notices because it has some important information I need with debugging... with that being said, I find the undefined variables to be a real pain in the butt.

For example, to remove an undefined variable notice I have to turn the following code:

```
if($the_month != $row['the_month'])
```

into

```
if(isset($the_month)  &&  $the_month != $row['the_month'])
```

Is there another way around this? This solution seems like a time waster to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the variable before using it. It's the only way to be sure.

A lot of web hosts still have `register_globals` enabled. This allows any visitor to inject variables into your script by adding stuff to the query string.

For example, if your script is called as `example.php?the_month=5`, the variable `$the_month` is automatically filled with 5. This can be **very dangerous**, because someone might be able to mess with important variables related to security! For this reason, `register_globals` is now deprecated.

But that doesn't change the fact that a lot of web hosts still have it enabled, so every PHP developer must define every variable to something safe before using it. *Otherwise you have no guarantee that the variable will contain what you think it does.*

Comment: Great answer: This is why KeenLearner is getting the warning, its a very valid warning.

Answer (score 7):

This answer may help as it is similar:

[PHP: printing undefined variables without warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376623/php-printing-undefined-variables-without-warning)

For example:

> You can run it with the error
>   suppression operator @.
>
> `echo @$variable;`
>
> However, it's best not to ignore unset
>   variables. Unset variables could
>   indicate a logical error on the
>   script, and it's best to ensure all
>   variables are set before use.

Answer (score 3):

Always make sure that `$the_month` is set to something, even `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You must not carelessly access variables that may or may not be defined, it's that simple. Just because PHP lets you do it doesn't mean it's a sane way to write code. Please refer to my extensive answer to a similar question here: [How to avoid isset() and empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly/1960588#1960588)