# Select count(*) from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, count

How can I select `count(*)` from two different tables (call them `tab1` and `tab2`) having as result:

```
Count_1   Count_2
123       456
```

I've tried this:

```
select count(*) Count_1 from schema.tab1 union all select count(*) Count_2 from schema.tab2
```

But all I have is:

```
Count_1
123
456
```

Answer (score 436, accepted):

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tab1
        ) AS count1,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tab2
        ) AS count2
FROM    dual
```

Comment: why do you need dual? what does that mean?

Comment: It's a fake table with one record. You can't have SELECT without FROM in Oracle.

Comment: dual is a table in oracle db's to which all accounts can access
you can use it for common needs like:
"SELECT sysdate FROM dual"

Comment: @Quassnoi, oh I see for Oracle. 1up

Comment: Dont you think using SELECT COUNT(1) is a bit more efficient than SELECT COUNT(*)?

Comment: It makes no difference, Oracle won't evaluate anything inside COUNT(*).

Comment: The DUAL table is my number one annoyance with Oracle SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329/what-are-five-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-language/564388#564388

Comment: Use any table you want then - (ALL_TABLES WHERE ROWNUM = 1) whatever.

But Dual in 10g has no i/o

Comment: Note that DB/2 does not support this syntax.

Comment: @Stéphane: this happens when you try Oracle code on PostgreSQL. Lose the `FROM dual`.

Comment: how can I make a group by from the result of those 2 select?

Comment: @sliders_alpha: please post it as another question, providing some sample data and desired resultset.

Comment: For MySql, remove the "FROM dual".

Answer (score 101):

As additional information, to accomplish same thing in SQL Server, you just need to remove the "FROM dual" part of the query.

Comment: I was just getting ready to say "But what about MS SQL, when I saw your comment.  Thank you for anticipating the need!

Answer (score 66):

Just because it's slightly different:

```
SELECT 'table_1' AS table_name, COUNT(*) FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT 'table_2' AS table_name, COUNT(*) FROM table_2
UNION
SELECT 'table_3' AS table_name, COUNT(*) FROM table_3
```

It gives the answers transposed (one row per table instead of one column), otherwise I don't think it's much different. I think performance-wise they should be equivalent.

Comment: You'd better put UNION ALL here.

Comment: What difference could adding "ALL" make with three single row queries? The results must be the same either way, surely?

Comment: UNION without ALL groups results. If there are 2 rows in table_1 and table_2, and 3 rows in table_3, you'll get two rows in your resultset, and won't be able to tell from resultset how many rows does table_2 have: 2 or 3.

Comment: Yes, but I select the table name, which makes the results unique. Otherwise you'd be correct, but what value would there be in several numbers without context? ;-)

Comment: This is also a good way to use a CTE (WITH SELECT) statement for each count.

Answer (score 36):

My experience is with SQL Server, but could you do:

```
select (select count(*) from table1) as count1,
  (select count(*) from table2) as count2
```

In SQL Server I get the result you are after.

Answer (score 20):

Other slightly different methods:

```
with t1_count as (select count(*) c1 from t1),
     t2_count as (select count(*) c2 from t2)
select c1,
       c2
from   t1_count,
       t2_count
/

select c1,
       c2
from   (select count(*) c1 from t1) t1_count,
       (select count(*) c2 from t2) t2_count
/
```

Answer (score 18):

```
    select 
    t1.Count_1,t2.Count_2
    from 
(SELECT count(1) as Count_1 FROM tab1) as t1, 
(SELECT count(1) as Count_2 FROM tab2) as t2
```

Answer (score 12):

A quick stab came up with:

```
Select (select count(*) from Table1) as Count1, (select count(*) from Table2) as Count2
```

Note: I tested this in SQL Server, so `From Dual` is not necessary (hence the discrepancy).

Comment: I tested this also in Postgres and 'From Dual' is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 9):

For a bit of completeness - this query will create a query to give you a count of all of the tables for a given owner.

```
select 
  DECODE(rownum, 1, '', ' UNION ALL ') || 
  'SELECT ''' || table_name || ''' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) ' ||
  ' FROM ' || table_name  as query_string 
 from all_tables 
where owner = :owner;
```

The output is something like

```
SELECT 'TAB1' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM TAB1
 UNION ALL SELECT 'TAB2' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM TAB2
 UNION ALL SELECT 'TAB3' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM TAB3
 UNION ALL SELECT 'TAB4' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM TAB4
```

Which you can then run to get your counts. It's just a handy script to have around sometimes.

Comment: I like the answer but I think you should add the owner to the "FROM"-part of the query. Otherwise you have to execute the query with the owner which might not directly be available.

Answer (score 8):

As I can't see any other answer bring this up.

**If** you don't like sub-queries **and** have primary keys in each table you can do this:

```
select count(distinct tab1.id) as count_t1,
       count(distinct tab2.id) as count_t2
    from tab1, tab2
```

But performance wise I believe that Quassnoi's solution is better, and the one I would use.

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2) FROM    dual;`

Answer (score 8):

Here is from me to share

**Option 1 - counting from same domain from different table**

```
select distinct(select count(*) from domain1.table1) "count1", (select count(*) from domain1.table2) "count2" 
from domain1.table1, domain1.table2;
```

**Option 2 - counting from different domain for same table**

```
select distinct(select count(*) from domain1.table1) "count1", (select count(*) from domain2.table1) "count2" 
from domain1.table1, domain2.table1;
```

**Option 3 - counting from different domain for same table with "union all" to have rows of count**

```
select 'domain 1'"domain", count(*) 
from domain1.table1 
union all 
select 'domain 2', count(*) 
from domain2.table1;
```

Enjoy the SQL, I always do :)

Answer (score 6):

```
select (select count(*) from tab1) count_1, (select count(*) from tab2) count_2 from dual;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
--============= FIRST WAY (Shows as Multiple Row) ===============
SELECT 'tblProducts' [TableName], COUNT(P.Id) [RowCount] FROM tblProducts P
UNION ALL
SELECT 'tblProductSales' [TableName], COUNT(S.Id) [RowCount] FROM tblProductSales S


--============== SECOND WAY (Shows in a Single Row) =============
SELECT  
(SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM   tblProducts) AS ProductCount,
(SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM   tblProductSales) AS SalesCount
```

Answer (score 5):

If the tables (or at least a key column) are of the same type just make the union first and then count.

```
select count(*) 
  from (select tab1key as key from schema.tab1 
        union all 
        select tab2key as key from schema.tab2
       )
```

Or take your satement and put another sum() around it.

```
select sum(amount) from
(
select count(*) amount from schema.tab1 union all select count(*) amount from schema.tab2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @all int
SET @all = (select COUNT(*) from tab1) + (select count(*) from tab2)
Print @all
```

or

```
SELECT (select COUNT(*) from tab1) + (select count(*) from tab2)
```

Answer (score 0):

JOIN with different tables

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (  
SELECT DISTINCT table_a.ID  FROM table_a JOIN table_c ON table_a.ID  = table_c.ID   );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tbl1
        )
        +
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tbl2
        ) 
    as TotalCount
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked. This calculates the overall sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google BigQuery this will work.

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(Table_1_Id_Count) AS Table_1_Id_Count,
  SUM(Table_2_Id_Count) AS Table_2_Id_Count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Id AS Table_1_Id,
      date,
      COUNT(Id) AS Table_1_Id_Count,
      0 AS Table_2_Id_Count
    FROM
      `your_project_name.Table_1`
    GROUP BY
      Id,
      date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Id AS Table_2_Id,
      date,
      0 AS Table_1_Id_Count,
      COUNT(Id) AS Table_2_Id_Count
    FROM
      `your_project_name.Table_2`
    GROUP BY
      Id,
      date
  )
GROUP BY
  date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subqueries:

```
Select t1.key, t1.col, t2.col, 
    , (Select count(*)
        From table3
        Where key = t1.key) as Count1
    , (Select count(*)
        From table4
        Where key = t1.key) as Count2
From table1 t1
Join table2 t2 on t2.key = t1.key
Where t1.key in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

select
(select count(*) from tab1 where `field` like 'value') +
(select count(*) from tab2 where `field` like 'value')
count

Answer (score -2):

```
select @count = sum(data) from
(
select count(*)  as data from #tempregion
union 
select count(*)  as data from #tempmetro
union
select count(*)  as data from #tempcity
union
select count(*)  as data from #tempzips
) a
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting. Please have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is wrong. Cannot use union (should use union all).