# SQL: Combine Select count(*) from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you combine multiple select count(*) from different table into one return?

I have a similar sitiuation as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

but I want one return.

I tried Union all but it spit back 3 separate rows of count. How do you combine them into one?

```
select count(*) from foo1 where ID = '00123244552000258'
union all 
select count(*) from foo2 where ID = '00123244552000258'
union all
select count(*) from foo3 where ID = '00123244552000258'
```

edit: I'm on MS SQL 2005

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(select count(*) from foo1 where ID = '00123244552000258')
+
(select count(*) from foo2 where ID = '00123244552000258')
+
(select count(*) from foo3 where ID = '00123244552000258')
```

This is an easy way.

Comment: Do we know how efficient this is on large tables of data?

Comment: The select count(*) should be based off an index on ID if available, and if one is not looking at the data it should be added. After that the addition is relatively simple.

Answer (score 21):

I'm surprised no one has suggested this variation:

```
SELECT SUM(c)
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM foo1 WHERE ID = '00123244552000258'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo2 WHERE ID = '00123244552000258'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo3 WHERE ID = '00123244552000258'
);
```

Comment: Actually I see it's similar to the answer given by @Gren but this example is more concrete w.r.t. the OP's question.

Comment: This works on SQL Server Compact Edition whereas sub-queries in the `SELECT` statement will fail.

Comment: But wouldn't union all be slower than just adding the results? As specified in Chris' answer?

Comment: Hard to tell without testing them head to head on the same dataset and same hardware.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, my solution uses UNION in a derived table, and the accepted answer uses three scalar subqueries. One may perform better than the other in a given RDBMS, and that depends on the query optimizer implementation in your RDBMS product.

Comment: Wouldn't this yield wrong result if the count(*) of any two (or more) subqueries were the same value? because the UNION would make it distinct and "duplicate" counts would not get added.

Comment: @BayakfromSiwa, When we use `UNION ALL` it does not eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 18):

```
select 
  (select count(*) from foo) as foo
, (select count(*) from bar) as bar
, ...
```

Answer (score 10):

Basically you do the counts as sub-queries within a standard select.

An example would be the following, this returns 1 row, two columns

```
SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE MyCol = 'MyValue') AS MyTableCount,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE MyCol = 'MyValue') AS YourTableCount,
```

Comment: ***not valid*** `SELECT MyTableCount + YourTableCount`

Answer (score 3):

You can combine your counts like you were doing before, but then you could sum them all up a number of ways, one of which is shown below:

```
SELECT SUM(A) 
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS A
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 AS A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS A
) AS B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(counts) from (
select count(1) as counts from foo 
union all
select count(1) as counts from bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could name all fields and add an outer select on those fields:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM ( your initial query here ) TableAlias
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For oracle:

```
select( 
select count(*) from foo1 where ID = '00123244552000258'
+
select count(*) from foo2 where ID = '00123244552000258'
+
select count(*) from foo3 where ID = '00123244552000258'
) total from dual;
```

Comment: ***Question is about SQL SERVER***