# count(*) in where clause when dealing with multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `augus1dl_ecom`.`test` 
(
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     `cn_no` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     `amt` DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `augus1dl_ecom`.`test2` 
(
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `docket_id` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL, 
     `cn_id` INT NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `augus1dl_ecom`.`test` (`id`, `cn_no`, `amt`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'A', '100'), (NULL, 'B', '200');

INSERT INTO `augus1dl_ecom`.`test2` (`id`, `docket_id`, `cn_id`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'DK1', '1'), (NULL, 'DK2', '2'), (NULL, 'DK3', '1') ;
```

In the `test` table the `cn_no` is unique. But in `test2` table, a single `cn_no` (refers to `cn_id`) could be inserted more than once.

I mean `test.id = test2.cn_id`.

Now I run the following query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM test2 a, test b 
WHERE b.id = a.cn_id AND b.cn_no = 'A'
```

It runs successfully. But I don't need data, I need the number of rows/entries. So I run the following query to retrieve number of rows (count) from `test`, depending condition which is in `test2`:

```
SELECT count(a.*) 
FROM test2 a, test b 
WHERE b.id = a.cn_id AND b.cn_no = 'A';
```

But the query fails with an error. This question was suggested as duplicate of [SQL: Combine Select count(*) from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279569/sql-combine-select-count-from-multiple-tables) but it is not. Here I want `count(*)` depending on the data which is available in another table. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Combine Select count(\*) from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279569/sql-combine-select-count-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: Just use `SELECT count(*)` instead of `count(a.*)`. You would get the same amount of lines event if `a.*` worked. `count` counts a single column. `count(*)` is just a shortcut that means "count number of lines, I do not care for which column. `count(a.*)` is equivalent to `count(id, cn_no, ...)` which is invalid syntax.

Comment: But `count (column_name)` does not count field with `NULL` values. It could be a problem in future, working with other scenario.

Comment: Count is an aggregate function so you need to add a group by clause, ie group by b.id

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(a.*) FROM test2 a INNER JOIN test b ON b.id=a.cn_id WHERE b.cn_no='A' GROUP BY(b.id);
```

new query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.* FROM test2 a INNER JOIN test b ON b.id=a.cn_id WHERE WHERE b.cn_no='A' 
) AS final
```

I suggest you use `inner join` they are easy and very efficient. Hope it helps. if it doesn't do let me know I haven't tested it.

Comment: Try `GROUP BY (a.id)`

Comment: @user3764374 hey now try the new query. It works with my system