# Getting count(*) value from multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, date, count

I found a solution to my query in this site. I need to get the count(*) value from multiple tables [Select count(*) from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

My other problem is to get the DATE values of those multiple tables that returns > 1 row count. I have to compare the dates and get the latest. I have to query from 12 tables. Assuming I got > 1 value for tables 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, I will need to compare their DATE values.
Sample code:

```
SELECT(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   table1) AS count1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   table2) AS count2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   table3) AS count3 FROM dual

count1 count2 count3
  3       2     2
```

I need to select the MOST RECENT date in these tables.

```
Select date from table1 order by date desc
Select date from table2 order by date desc
Select date from table3 order by date desc
```

How am I supposed to do that without table scanning?

**EDIT:**
Okay. The instructions said 
"Get matching records from tables 1-12 using the id as the key". 
If there are no records, display "No record found"
Else: get the record with the latest date by comparing data_encoded from all tables.

Comment: I can't tell what you're after.  Some example output would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the most recent date for 12 tables. I will also try the code below given by Bohemian

Comment: @OMG Ponies. No, 12 tables with different date column values.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty hard to tell what you're after, but here's a guess:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1) AS latest1,
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table2) AS latest2,
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table3) AS latest3,
    -- etc
FROM dual;
```

You can avoid table scans by having indexes on `date`, in which case the optimizer should do index-only scans (very fast).

Comment: Got this working. Now I have to get the MAX() date of the results that has an output. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to group them and order it and select the first date

select ID, Date, count(date)
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id
inner join table3 t3 where t1.id = t3.id
etc..
group by date
order by date desc

something long that line