# How to learn rows number of different tables with one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, count, rows

I have different MySQL tables such as **users**, **news** and etc. I want to know users number, news number with one MySQL query. How can I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select count(*) from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION`.

`SELECT 'users', COUNT(*) as c FROM users UNION SELECT 'names', COUNT(*) as c FROM names;`