# How to get the total rows on a database with one query

Tags: sql, sqlite, rows

I have a database with two tables, I want to get the total of rows in those tables with a single query.
So far T tried:

```
SELECT (count(bill.*) + count(items.*)) as TTL FROM bill, items // Failed 
SELECT count(*) as TTL FROM bill, items // wrong total
SELECT (count(bill.ID_B) + count(items.ID_I)) as TTL FROM bill, items // wrong total
SELECT count(bill.ID_B + items.ID_I) as TTL FROM bill, items // return the biggest total
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two sub-queries:

```
select (select count(1) from bill) + (select count(1) from items);
```

Comment: @JDwyer Would you explain Why?

Comment: Now-a-days the databases probably make these operate the same. The conventional wisdom was that selecting a constant a.k.a 1 or 'a' is faster than selecting values from the table. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1