# Can a fake table be created in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if it is possible to create a fake table in SQL Server 2005.

Because when I tried I got an error

> *Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Invalid object name 'dual'.*

This is what I  [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

and it did not work. For test purpose I have created a test table to execute the query.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQL Server you are allowed to leave out the `FROM` clause. So you don't need a fake table.

Instead of writing

```
select 42
from dual;
```

just write

```
select 42;
```

Comment: Just a note on your problem: the 'dual' table is an Oracle concept, which is why it was failing for you in mssql. Personally I find ms sql server a lot simpler - as @a_horse_with_no_name said: you're allowed to 'select' without a 'from' clause.

Comment: @ari: Actually several DBMS do *not* support a `SELECT` without a `FROM` (Oracle, DB2, Firebird). They all have some kind of "dual" table for that case.