# How to execute a group of 'select count(*)' queries as a batch in Java?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**EDIT : besides the answer by Gordon, [I found this question answered beautifully on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)**

While we can execute a group of insert/update statements as a batch, there is no such provision for select statements. I understand that it's impossible to do so because they return results that may have many columns.

However, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` returns just one value and that is an integer. Is there a way to run a group of such queries as a batch and retrieve the results as an int array?

My particular requirement is to run these queries for a bunch of tables on the same database and then repeat this for more databases. Consider this example:

```
    String[] queries = {"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1",
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2",
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3" };
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    for(String q: queries){            
           st.addBatch(q);
    }       
    st.executeBatch();
```

In this case, the executeBatch() command will only return the number of rows affected, which will be zero (I suppose) in this case for each statement.

Is there a way to make a batch of such statements considering that they return only one value each? Any workaround?

**Specific requirements follow..**

SQL Procedures are out of question as I have to do this on many different databases and I don't have any access except to read them. I mean, I *can* store procedures there, but I've been told not to modify the database in any way and just to read from it. Additionally, the number of databases may increase later and I wouldn't be there to install these procedures on them, so I don't want that dependency in order for this solution to be truly flexible.

I am using Java with SQL Server 2008 for building a webpage that gets count values from a bunch of tables on various databases and displays them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just run one query?  You an do:

```
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) as table1cnt,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2) as table2cnt,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3) as table3cnt;
```

You can also return one value per row, but you'll want an additional column to identify the table:

```
select which, cnt
from ((SELECT 'table1' as which, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1) union all
      (SELECT 'table2' as which, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table2) union all
      (SELECT 'table3' as which, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table3)
     ) t
```

Comment: I think the `union` query can be simplified: you don't need the outer `select` statement.

Comment: @ThomasMueller . . . That is true.