# SSIS take oracle variable and use them in a ssis resultset

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, resultset

I have an execute sql task in one of my ssis package. I need to check if some of my tables have values inside them and store the result in a variable.I then need to use those variables later on in my package. My question is how do I assign those oracle variable from my sql task to my user variable in an ssis package.

I have something that look like this:

```
Variable
s5 NUMBER 
variable s6 number 
variable s7 number 
begin
select count(*) into s5 from GC_somethin where rownum < 100;
select count(*) into s6 from GC_somethingabc where rownum < 100;
select count(*) into s7 from GC_dddcccc where rownum < 100;
END;
select s5 AS 's51' from dual;
```

I have also fix my resultset to single row and in result set I have avariable name like s51 and the name of the variable I assigned to that. IT gives my the following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to
>   variable "TSERVADD_AFTER": "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0015005".

Comment: You'll need to perform those selects and store the results in SSIS  variables.  You can't access Oracle variables in SSIS.

Comment: How do I do that.I am kinda new to SSIS.

Comment: Don't know all the steps off the top of my head.   I would google something like "SSIS execute sql task results in scalar variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use SSIS variables instead of Oracle.

1. Create **3 variables**, ie. s5, s6, s6 with intiger type.
2. Create **Execute Sql Tasks** for every query, set result set to single row and assign results sets to previously created variables.
3. Use filled variables in SSIS.

Of course, **reformat** your queries to:

```
select count(*) as s5 from GC_somethin where rownum < 100
```

Sql statement for single Sql Task:

```
with cte as(
select count(*) as s5, null as s6, null as s7 from GC_somethin 
union all 
select null as s5, count(*) as s6, null as s7 from GC_somethingabc 
union all
select null as s5, null as s6, count(*) as s7 from GC_dddcccc 
)
select max(s5) as s5, max(s6) as s6, max(s7) as s7 from cte
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a single sql task.

Comment: Yes, look at my edit or... use this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/606238/663364)