# getting count one in very first time but the field is null when using count query

Tags: android, count

getting count value 1 in very first time but the field is null value, when using count query and If i am inserting any data into this field then count value remains 1 and then again i insert next data into this then it counts 2 after that it works fine but in very first time it counts 1 despite the field has null.

```
int notesCount=0;

    (SELECT COUNT("+Constants.NOTES+") FROM (select distinct "+Constants.NOTES+" from "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME_CONTACTS+ ")) AS notesCount
```

Comment: and what the question?

Comment: i need to count how many notes added and want to print it for my report section

Comment: #ssh sir have you any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select count(\*) from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: i have inserted the value in notes column and i am used to check if <> null then it will count no. of notes, thats the problem that i am facing. and every things count except notes.

Comment: I got solution, here for notes add new query  (SELECT COUNT("+Constants.NOTES+") FROM (select distinct "+Constants.NOTES+" from "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME_CONTACTS+ ")) AS notesCount))   but one issues there that is notes doesnt have any value and it count 1 in very first time

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto i added my code

Answer (score 0):

These are actually two separate queries. Execute them one by one.

Comment: i have done using only one query so here why i use distinct query