# Select count(*) from multiple tables in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I select count(*) from two different tables (table1 and table2) having as result:

```
Count_1   Count_2
123       456
```

I've tried this:

```
select count(*) as Count_1 from table1 
UNION select count(*) as Count_2 from table2;
```

But here's what I get:

```
Count_1
123
456
```

I can see a solution for Oracle and SQL server here, but either syntax doesn't work for MS Access (I am using Access 2013).
[Select count(*) from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606234/5556320)

I would prefer to do this using SQL (because I am developing my query dynamically within VBA).

Comment: you should have a look into Access TRANSFORM PIVOT.

Comment: Thank you @mxix, that sounds promising. I want to give it a closer look, but for now Horaciux's response below gets me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross join two subqueries which return the separate counts:

```sql
SELECT sub1.Count_1, sub2.Count_2
FROM
    (SELECT Count(*) AS Count_1 FROM table1) AS sub1,
    (SELECT Count(*) AS Count_2 FROM table2) AS sub2;
```

Comment: A comment disappeared, but thanks for the suggestion to change `SELECT *` to `SELECT sub1.Count_1, sub2.Count_2`

Answer (score 3):

```
    Select TOP 1
     (Select count(*) as Count from table1) as count_1, 
     (select count(*) as Count from table2) as count_2
   From table1
```

Comment: Thanks @Horaciux, this one gives me an error message "Query input must contain at least one table or query."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933518/table-less-union-query-in-ms-access-jet-ace

Comment: Take a look at the link. It mentions how to manage this scenario. See if my edit work, I don't have access here

Comment: Thank you @Horaciux, that does work. I actually took out "as Count" from the middle because I didn't think that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is a SUM (or AVG) like this what you are trying to achieve?

```
select sum(count) from (
select count(*) as Count from table1 
UNION select count(*) as Count from table2
);
```

Comment: Thanks, actually no. I don't need a sum of two counts, I just need them to show up side by side.

Comment: Oh I get it, then I would check Horaciux answer