# Mysql Select authors with more posts

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database: tb_authors and tb_posts.

I need to display a list of authors ordered by the number of posts each one has in descending order.

Both tables have in common an `id_author` key.

Anyone can help me?

Ok, so far I got this:

```
SELECT tb_authors.*, COUNT(tb_posts.*) AS thecount FROM tb_posts, tb_authors WHERE tb_authors.id_author = tb_posts.id_author ORDER BY thecount DESC;
```

But it's not working. It returns 1 column with one Author and the `thecount` has the value of total posts.

Comment: Have you done any relational queries before?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to select and count at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, the table names and common key are enough to answer this one.

```
SELECT tb_authors.*, COUNT(tb_posts.*) AS thecount WHERE tb_posts.id_author = tb_authors.id_author ORDER BY thecount DESC
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help!
It returns an syntax error near '*) AS thecount

Comment: Hmm, I'm missing something(this isn't a query I do often either).  Try reading this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables