# SQL Query - Get the count from many tables

Tags: mysql

I have an employee table, dependent table

> employee table

- empid
- empname
- status(working,retired,deceased,terminated)

> Dependent

- id
- empid
- name
- relationtoemp
- age....etc

Now, i want to query to get the count of total employees, count of total employees in each status(working,retired..), count of all dependants for all employees

Any help?

Comment: take a look into `count()` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: you need to different query for this check count() and group by when you try and not get than come back here

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select count(\*) from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is `"Count"`

For exemple : `'SELECT COUNT(empid) FROM employee WHERE status = working'`

This will give you the number of employees which status is "working"

Comment: YEs i got that with single table .but i need to include dependants table also and get the count in single query

Answer (score 0):

This will give you counts grouped by status

```
SELECT COUNT(emp.empid)  as counts, status
FROM employee emp join employee2 emp2 on emp.empid = emp2.empid
group by status
```

Comment: YEs i got that with single table .but i need to include dependants table also and get the count in single query

Comment: this will be only counting empid where there is a match to your dependent table, so this will do what you need

Comment: if there are no dependent records in table2 they will be removed form the count by the inner join

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Prepared Statements` like this:

```
set @sql = (
    select group_concat(distinct 
        concat(
            "sum(case when `status`='", e.status, "' then 1 end) as `", e.status, "`"
        )
    ) 
    from employee e
);

set @sql = concat("select count(e.empid) total_emp, (select count(*) from dependent) total_dep , ", @sql, " from employee e");

prepare stmt from @sql;

execute stmt;
```

The first part will dynamically generate columns for each employee status, and with a subselect you can count the total of dependents.