# Row count in a multi-table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate the rows in the table with each other condition.
I have this in some way, but it does not work.

```
$sql = "SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM orders) as total,
  UNION ALL
 (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM orders  WHERE status='1') as ok,
  UNION ALL
 (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM orders  WHERE status='2') as ko";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) as total, sum(status = 1) as ok, sum(status = 2) as ko
from orders;
```

Note:  This assumes that `status` is really stored as a number.  Don't use single quotes for numeric constants (do use them when you really intend a string).

Answer (score 0):

You can `count` data of more than one `table`using `simple query`

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(name) AS `total`, (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM orders  WHERE status='1') as `second`, (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM orders  WHERE status='2') as `third` FROM orders";
```

For more information [please check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)