# Laravel mysql How can count field of multiple table in same query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have three mysql table named `users`,'`clients`' and '`products`'. I want to count the 'id' field of every table in same query. Is it possible? please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `count the 'id' field of every table` means ?

Comment: I want to result like as 
total_user = 10,
total_clients  = 15,
total_products = 20

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables). Might give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks @Jixone bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please this statement

```
SELECT u.total_users, c.total_clients, p.total_products (
 SELECT COUNT(id) as total_users FROM users
) as u,
(
  SELECT COUNT(id) as total_clients FROM clients
) as c,
(
   SELECT COUNT(id) as total_products FROM products
) as p
```