# Select count of multiple values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a radio station's database of songs added into reports by individual programs. I would like to select album, album_id, count of songs in an album, and count of album occurrences in reports history of a single artist. So I want the following result:

```
| album_id | album_name | track_count | report_occurrence_count |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1        | Name 1     | 10          | 25                      |
| 2        | Name 2     | 15          | 65                      |
| 3        | Name 3     | 23          | 11                      |
```

EDIT: Relevant tables to select values from:

```
| album     | artist     | track       | report_track   |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| id        | id         | id          | id             |
| artist_id | name       | album_id    | report_id      |
| name      | ...        | artist_id   | track_id       |
| ...       | ...        | ...         | ...            |
```

I can get either the track count or the report occurrences count, but not both. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT al.id as album_id, al.name, al.identifier, count(tr.album_id) as track_count, 
count(rt.track_id) as report_occurrence
FROM playlist__album as al, playlist__artist as ar, playlist__track as tr,
playlist__report_track as rt
WHERE al.artist_id = ar.id
and tr.album_id = al.id
and rt.track_id = tr.id
and ar.id = 39887
group by album_id
```

But that gives me the report_occurrence count to both track_count and report_occurrence_count columns. If I remove count(rt.track_id) as report_occurrence, I get the correct value for track_count. I've tried the method found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables) but that gives me the count of all tracks by artist, instead of count by album.

DB tables are like so:
[image: tables]

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  **Always use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.**

Comment: can you provide the DB tables ?

Comment: Yes, just now fixed the link to image.

Comment: it's little hard to track all your tables if you can display the tables you want to select from as the same way you displayed the result it will be better

Comment: Sure, added relevant tables with relevant fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you need  distinct track_no for tracks

```
SELECT al.id as album_id
 , al.name
 , al.identifier
 , count(distinct tr.track_no) as track_count
 , count(rt.track_id) as report_occurrence
FROM playlist__album as al
INNER JOIN  playlist__artist as ar ON al.artist_id = ar.id
INNER JOIN  playlist__track as tr ON and tr.album_id = al.id
INNER JOIN  playlist__report_track as rt ON  rt.track_id = tr.id
WHERE ar.id = 39887
group by album_id
```

And you should avoid old implicit join syntax based on where and comma separated list of tables name, and use explicit join syntax.

Comment: Yes, adding distinct worked for count(distinct tr.id)! Will also check my syntax and replace commas with joins. Cheers!