# Laravel Union "Call to a member function union() on int"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Error: Call to a member function union() on int**

```php
$category = Category::select('name')->count();
$city = City::select('city')->count();
$client = Client::select('name')->count();

$property = Property::select('name')->count()
                    ->union($category)
                    ->union($city)
                    ->union($client)
                    ->get();

dd($property);
```

Comment: The error says it all, you can not call `count()->union($category)`

Comment: @ArSeN how should I act in order to get all counts in union?

Comment: @ArSeN First do all the unions and put count at the end

Comment: @codedge 
"Error: Call to a member function getBindings() on int"
`$property=Property::select('name')->union($category)->union($city)->union($client)->count();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an array of counts, union won't work for you. [Select count(*) from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)

```php
$counts = [
    'city' => City::count(),
    'category' => Category::count(),
    'client' => Client::count(),
    'property' => Property::count(),
];
```

There's no need to keep it in one query.