# Next step after PHP: Perl or Python?

Tags: python, perl

It might seem it has been asked numerous times, but in fact it hasn't. I did my research, and now I'm eager to hear *others' opinions*.

I have experience with **PHP 5**, both with functional and object oriented programming methods. I created a few feature-minimalistic websites.

Professionals may agree about PHP not being a programming language that encourages good development habits. (I believe it's not the task of the tool, but this doesn't matter.) Furthermore, **its performance is also controversial** and often said to be poor compared to competitors.

In the [42nd podcast at Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/podcast-42/) a developer from Poland asked what language he should learn in order to improve his skills. Jeff and Joel suggested that **every one of them would help**, altough there are specific ones that are better in some ways.
Despite they made some great points, it didn't help me that much.

From a beginner point of view, <s>there are not</s> one may not see (correction suggested by [S. Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott)) many differences between **Perl & Python**. I would like You to emphasize their strenghts and weaknesses and name a few unique services.

Of course, this wouldn't be fair as I could also check both of them. So here's my wishlist and requirements to help You help me.

First of all, I'd like to follow **OOP structures** and use it fundamentally. I partly planned a multiuser **CMS** using MySQL and XML, so the greater the implementations are, the better. Due to its foreseen nature, **string manipulation** will be used intensively.

If there aren't great differences, comparisons should probably mention syntax and other tiny details that don't matter in the first place.

So, here's my question: which one should I try **first** -- Perl || Python?

---

### Conclusion

Both Perl and Python have their own fans, which is great. I'd like to say I'm grateful for all participation -- there is no trace of any flame war.

I accepted the most valued answer, although there are many great mini-articles below. As suggested more often, I will go with Python first. Then I'll try Perl later on. Let me see which one fits my mind better.

During the development of my special CMS, I'm going to ask more regarding programming doubts -- because developers now can count on each other! Thank you.

**Edit:** There were some people suggesting to choose Ruby or Java instead. Java has actually disappointed me. Maybe it has great features, maybe it hasn't. I wouldn't enjoy using it.

In addition, I was told to use Ruby. So far, most of the developers I communicate with have quite bad opinion about Ruby. I'll see it myself, but that's the last element on my priority list.

Comment: Syntax doesn't matter? Say that to all the computer languages that aren't turing complete due to the lack of key syntactic constructs.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269417/which-language-should-i-use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319421/what-is-the-best-programming-language-for-web-development-and-why

Comment: This question is more specific. I believe it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I only said that syntax is less important than the underlying features of any given programming language. It takes time to get used to it though.

Comment: Left off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150043/python-v-perl

Comment: "From a beginner point of view, there are not many differences between Perl & Python."  Then why ask?  Not sure what that means or why it's in the question.

Comment: S. Lott: I honestly like to distinguish these two languages, however, I simply can't do that with low expereince. So I'm interested in real life opinions. And they are coming... :)

Comment: @pestaa: Your question says "there are not many differences".  Perhaps you should take that out of your question to make it clear that you do not have your opinions already formed.

Comment: Is there a reason you are limiting yourself to Perl and Python? Ruby is usually lumped in with Python and Perl. Why leave it out? Java is a strictly typed OOP language. Why not consider Java/jsp?

Comment: Why does everybody and his uncle have to write a cms these days? Those kids today! We used to write newsreaders all day long in the good ol' times.

Answer (score 25):

Perl is a very nice language and CPAN has a ton of mature modules that will save you a lot of time. Furthermore, Perl is really moving forwards nowadays with a lot of interesting projects (unlike what uninformed fanboys like to spread around). Even a [Perl 6 implementation](http://rakudo.org/) is by now releasing working Perl 6.

I you want to do OO, I would recommend [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose.pm).

Comment: It warms my heart to see the Perl love here. As soon as I saw 'Python or Perl?' I was sure a thousand people were going to post about how Perl is dead. With frameworks like Moose and Perl 6 development moving very quickly, it's far from dead (plus my company uses it all over the place)

Comment: Careful jjnguy - you saw what happened the last time you said that. ;)

Comment: @rjh Seconded, but Perl 6 is not moving quickly :)

Comment: Haha, indeed... and Perl 5 isn't exactly piling on new features either :/

Answer (score 11):

Honestly, the "majority" of my programming has been in Perl and PHP and I recently decided to do my latest project in Python, and I must admit it is very nice to program with. I was hesitant of the whole no curly braces thing as that's what I've always done, but it is really very clean. At the end of the day, though, you can make good web applications with all 3, but if you are dead-set on dropping PHP to try something new I would recommend Python and the Django framework.

Comment: Django is repeatedly said to be so cool. Is that really so good, or just a popular framework?

Comment: It is popular for a reason. :) As far as your PHP concerns on performance, PHP performance can be quite good if you do the right things: memcache, etc.

Comment: @pestaa: good usually leads to popular.  Few things can be popular and bad.  Unless there's some kind of trade monopoly (like Windows).

Comment: @Paolo: and Perl/Python with cache enabled might lead to even better performance. I want a solid base to build on.
@S. Lott: please don't start flame wars. :) I can name popular and bad things in the world of PHP. (Zend Framework for example. Or even PHP itself?)

Comment: @pestaa: I think if Wikipedia and Facebook can make PHP work for them, your performance should be fine. Don't drop the entire language because of a perceived idea that may not necessarily be true.

Comment: @pestaa: I'm not aware of any popular and bad things in the Python world.  I'm not interested in a flame war.  I'm saying that your question "good or just popular?" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Paolo: I do not have as much resource as Wikimedia Foundation or Facebook's fathers have. It is not a problem to optimize a CMS written in PHP, so it can generate a busy homepage within a second. What if I want it to be rendered within half a second?
@S. Lott: You seem one-sided regarding Python.

Comment: @pestaa: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. PHP is very capable.

Answer (score 10):

I'd go with Perl. Not everyone will agree with me here, but it's a great language well suited to system administration work, and it'll expose you to some more functional programming constructs. It's a great language for learning how to use the smallest amount of code for a given task, as well.

For the usage scenario you mentioned though, I think PHP may be your best bet still. Python does have some great web frameworks, however, so if you just want to try out a new language for developing web applications, Python might be your bet.

Comment: +1 I'm glad to finally see some Perlites. Pyvangelism seems to be huge on SO, and even with Perl 6 in the future, some people *ahem* are claiming that "Pearl" is dying...

Comment: I await Perl 6 with bated breath, but I fear that it's going the way of Duke Nukem Forever..

Comment: We got a Watchmen movie that was 20 years in the making (and sucked), and we got a Guns 'N' Roses album that was 13(-ish?) years in the making (and sucked), what's so insane about hoping for anything else?

Comment: Taking PHP's performance into consideration... I'd say no... I won't go with that... I really want the speed of light. :)

Answer (score 7):

I have no experience with Python.  I vouch strongly to learn Perl, not out of attrition, but because there is a TON to learn in the platform.  The key concepts of Perl are: Do What I Mean ([DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM)) and There's More Than One Way To Do It ([TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)).  This means, hypothetically there's often no wrong way to approach a problem if the problem is adequately solved.

Start with learning the base language of Perl, then extend yourself to learning the key Perl modules, like IO::File, DBI, HTML::Template, XML::LibXML, etc. etc. [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org) will be your resource.  [perlmonks.org](http://perlmonks.org) will be your guide.  Just about everything useful to do will likely have a module published.

Keep in mind that Perl is a dynamic and loosely structured language.  Perl is not the platform to enforce draconian OOP standards, but for good reason.  You'll find the language extremely flexible.

Where is Perl used?  System Admins use it heavily, as already mentioned.  You can still do excellent web apps either by simple CGI or MVC framework.

Comment: Why do you have an opinion on which of the two to choose if you have no experience with Python?

Comment: IO::File?  I can't imagine the criteria that would rate that a key module.

Comment: My answer is to educate.  The questioner will make their own decision.  If you feel so strongly, then I recommend putting in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't worked with Python much, but I can tell why I *didn't* like about Perl when I used it.

1. OO support feels tacked on.  OO in perl is very different from OO support in the other languages I've used (which include things like PHP, Java, and C#)
2. TMTOWTDI (There's More Than One Way To Do It).  Good idea in theory, terrible idea in practice as it reduces code readability.
3. Perl uses a lot of magic symbols.
4. Perl doesn't support named function arguments, meaning that you need to dig into the @_ array to get the arguments passed to a function (or rather, a sub as perl doesn't have the function keyword).  This means you'll see a lot of things like the example below (moved 'cause SO doesn't like code in numbered lists)

Having said all that, I'd look into Python.  Unless you want to go with something heavier-weight like C++ or C#/Java.

Oh, before I forgot: I wanted to put an example for 4 above, but SO doesn't like putting code in numbered lists:

```
sub mySub {
    #extremely common to see in Perl, as built-ins operators operate on the $_ scalar or @_ array implicitly
    my $arg1 = shift;
    my $arg2 = shift;
}
```

Comment: Nothing is perfect. I happen to think Python's docstrings have a particularly horrid-looking syntax. I mean, seriously. Triple-quoted strings. """This does not look like it should parse"""

Comment: "TMTOWTDI (There's More Than One Way To Do It). Good idea in theory"?  Really?  It doesn't sound like a good idea even in theory.  Ambiguity is always a problem.

Comment: I believe if the language constructs are in the way, you have either not fully learned the language or are misapplying it.  Most of these items are problems a novice must learn to deal with.

Comment: On the mySub example, use "my ($arg1, $arg2) = @_;"

Comment: @spoulson: True, I didn't think of doing it that way... I haven't dealt with Perl on a regular basis since Summer '06.

Comment: I, too found the OO aspects of Perl "tacked on" compared to Java, Ruby and even (shudder) C++. A friend I respect greatly, FWIW, calls Python "Perl done right".

Comment: It's quite easy to pass a hash into a Perl subroutine and use that to supply named arguments (in any order). sub get_dimensions { my %params = @_; my $area = $params{'width'} * $params{'length'}; }

Comment: OO WAS tacked on to Perl. Thats why we now have Ruby.

Comment: Actually personally, I can hardly wait for Perl6 to leave the other dynamic languages in the dust. There are so many things that you can easily do now, today, with Perl6, that you can't do nearly as easily in other languages. And it's not even done yet.

Comment: Perl OO was tacked on. It's simple, flexible, and if you want something more "purely" OO, use Moose. OO is not the be-all, end-all of programming paradigms.

Comment: Used properly TMTOWTDI *increases* readability as it gives you the flexibility to select the clearest way to express something. Used improperly... it gives you enough rope to tie a syntactical Gordian knot.

Comment: MooseX::Declare is best for Perl OO

Answer (score 7):

I recently made the step from Perl over to Python, after a couple of Perl-only years. Soon thereafter I discovered I had started to read through all kinds of Python-code just as it were any other easy to read text — something I've never done with Perl. Having to delve into third-party Perl code has always been kind of a nightmare for me, so this came as a very very nice surprise!

For me, this means Python-code is much easier to maintain, which on the long run makes Python much more attractive than Perl.

Answer (score 5):

Python is clean and elegant, and the fact that LOTS of C APIs have been wrapped, gives you powerful hooks to much. I also like the "[Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)".

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Explicit is better than implicit.
- Simple is better than complex.
- Complex is better than complicated.
- Flat is better than nested.
- Sparse is better than dense.
- Readability counts.
- Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
- Although practicality beats purity.
- Errors should never pass silently.
- Unless explicitly silenced.
- In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
- There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to
  do it.
- Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
- Now is better than never.
- Although never is often better than *right* now.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
- If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
- Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Comment: I really like your list, although I can't completely understand why many of them are here. Those are widely accepted or recommended programming activities.

Answer (score 4):

As a Perl programmer, I would normally say Perl.  But coming from PHP, I think Perl is too similar and you won't actually get that much out of it.  (Not because there isn't a lot to learn, but you are likely to program in Perl using the same style as you program in PHP.)

I'd suggest something completely different: Haskell (suggested by Joel), Lisp, Lua, JavaScript or C.  Any one of these would make you a better programmer by opening up new ways of looking at the world.

But there's no reason to stop learning PHP in the meantime.

For a good look at the dark side of these languages, I heartily recommend: [What are five things you hate about your favorite language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329/what-are-five-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-language)

Comment: PHP and Perl are C-like and share some language constructs, but only at the surface.  There is far more to learn from Perl than PHP.  I'm certain there's plenty to learn from a LISP language, but not just because it's unlike C.

Comment: Yeah.  I realized after I posted that the reason for discounting Perl in this case was because of habits, not content.

Comment: Admittedly, Perl is not for everyone.  But I'm fine with that.

Comment: Perl is very similar to PHP, but they're also very different. I think there are a lot of benefits to learning Perl from PHP (or vice versa, as I'm sortof doing). Just because Python is "more different" doesn't mean learning it will teach you more. But +1 for C - learning memory management is good!

Comment: Note that I completely side-step Python.  The nicest thing I could think to say was that the CPU-hogging Python scripts I've dealt with look very clean, which isn't all that nice.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest going through a beginner tutorial of each and decide for yourself which fits you better.  You'll find you can do what you need to do in either:

**[Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html)** ([Python Classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects))

**[Perl Tutorial](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2000/10/begperl1.html)** ([Perl Classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html))
(Couldn't find a single 'official' perl tutorial, feel free to suggest one)

---

In my experience python provides a cleaner, more straight-forward experience.

My issues with perl:

- ['use strict;', Taint, Warnings?](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2001/01/begperl6.html) - Ideally these shouldn't be needed.
- Passing variables: @*; vs. $*, vs shift
- Scoping [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html), [local](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html), [ours](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html)? (The local defintion seems to particularly point out some confusion with perl, "You really probably want to be using my instead, because local isn't what most people think of as "local".".)

In general with my perl skills I still find my self referencing documentation for built-in features.  Where as in python I find this less so. *(I've worked in both roughly the same amount of time, but my general programming expereince has grown with time.  In other words, I'd probably be a better perl programmer now)*

If your a unix command line guru though, perl may come more naturally to you.  Or, if your using it mainly as a replacement or extension to command line admin tasks, it may suit your needs fine.  In my opinion perl is "faster on the draw" at the command line than python is.

Comment: "use strict;" - it is a sign, if it is missing it means that program rewritten :).

Answer (score 2):

Why isn't there Ruby on your list? Maybe you should give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

"I'd like to follow OOP structure..." advocates for Python or, even more so if you're open, Ruby. On the other hand, in terms of existing libraries, the order is probably Perl > Python >> Ruby. In terms of your career, Perl on your resume is unlikely to make you stand out, while Python and Ruby may catch the eye of a hiring manager.

As a PHP programmer, you are probably going to see all 3 as somewhat "burdensome" to get a Web page up. All have good solutions for Web frameworks, but none is quite as focussed on rendering a Web page as is PHP.

I think that Python is quite likely to be a better choice for you than Perl. It has many good resources, a large community (although not as large as Perl, probably), "stands out" a little on a resume, and has a good reputation.

Comment: "In terms of your career..." That sentence sounds extremely unlikely. A manager won't look for "something cool," they'll look for the languages their company uses to develop software. A company that runs Perl won't hire you for knowing Ruby. Maybe if you know Ruby AND Perl...

Comment: Perl programmers are rare these days. So Perl might actually help you. Unless, of course, you're looking for a Python job. Chris has got a point.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I tend to disagree. I think (good) hiring managers are looking for signs of engagement with the community and _do_ take notice if a person is using languages / frameworks / approaches that are considered more "current". YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If those 2 are your only choices, I would choose Python.

Otherwise you should learn javascript.

No I mean *really* learn it...

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript? It isn't a server-side language. Did you mean Java?

Comment: Why isn't javascript a server-side language?  I'm quite sure I'm not the only one using it server-side.

Comment: Javascript's dirty little secret: hidden under all that DOM/HTML stuff is a very nice language.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't be doing web development with this language, either of them would do. If you are, you may find that doing web development in perl is a bit more complicated, since all of the frameworks require more knowledge of the language.
You can do nice things in both, but my opinion is that perl allows more rapid development.
 Also, perl's regexes rock!

Answer (score 0):

Every dynamic language is from same family. It does not matter Which is the tool you work with it matter how you do..

[PHP VS PYTHON OT PERL OR RUBY? Stop it](http://blog.oykko.com/2013/09/python-or-php.html)

As many comments mentioned python is cleaner well sometime whose curly brackets  are use full to. You just have to practice.