# Java recruitment test?

Tags: java

I have just applied for a Java developer job and the recruiter told me he wanted me to take an online Java test to see how my Java knowledge was. Fact questions with multiple answers.

Does anyone have idea what site it could be?

Tips on what should i prepare?

--

So, i got to make this test: Java 2 - Non-GUI
Which consisted of questions about:
Syntax
Class Definition
Utility Libraries
Math and String operations
The Java Runtime
Threads
Math and String Operations
Networking
Standard I/O
Object-Oriented Programming

Timed questions with multiple answers. Some of them were code to follow, those were usually as a jpeg. Good tip is to have Eclipse up and running so you can code quickly and test stuff.

Comment: If you applied for a position you're qualified for, there is no need to worry. Relax.

Comment: Try to answer these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-j2ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer

Comment: Yes, it's a junior Java developer position so they don't expect me to know everything. But I'm still bit worried because it's my first real developer job I've applied for. Fresh out of university :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to answer as many SO questions regarding java as possible. It's the best preparation you can do.

Comment: Yes, ive been browsing SO all day. So much good info here

Answer (score 3):

From my experience you cannot really prepare for such tests as their scope varies a lot but usually it just covers basic knowledge. Some have questions with special cases you won't ever experience under normal conditions and for which you can't really prepare unless you memorize the full java spec line by line for every java version. If a company asks you such questions... run, you don't want to work there.

Just stay calm and you won't have problems.

Comment: Haha run! yea, he told me that I could look things up though so they seem ok

Answer (score 2):

I've taken similar tests at [Brainbench](http://www.brainbench.com). It's highly likely it's either Brainbench or something very similar to it. My suggestion for study material would be to study similar topics to the [SCJP](http://www.sun.com/training/catalog/courses/CX-310-065.xml).

Comment: Nice, I'll have a look! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have done a similar test before. As previous answers have stated they tend to cover a wide range from obvious questions to problems that lead you to wonder about the sanity of the developers of the test...

One tip is to check the rules very carefully. Some allow you to use reference materials - if this is the case, it's worth having several tabs on your browser open to quick reference guides, as you usually have a few minutes per question. Some even allow you to run code - get yourself a good process for quickly running little test programs.

Another suggestion is to work through a book like [Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Puzzlers-Traps-Pitfalls-Corner/dp/032133678X) which has a lot of little quirky puzzles which help explain dusty corners of the Java spec. This will show you stuff that is similar to the really obscure puzzles that recruitment tests sometimes throw up.

Comment: Good tips! Thanks mate. He told me I could check books and APIs mean while. It was timed with 3 mins? per questions. And i could use 30-60 minutes for the whole test. He said dont stress :)