# Management round of a Java/Java EE interview

Tags: jakarta-ee

What kind of topics/questions one can expect in a management round of an interview for a Java/Java EE sr.developer position.

[EDIT] By management round I mean discussion with some one who is playing role of a project manager / technical manager. This round typically takes place after you are through with your coding tests and discussions with a sr.developer / tech lead.

Comment: what exactly is a 'management' round?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-j2ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856/senior-j2ee-interview-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will likely be looking for soft / interpersonal skills and general personality things. Things like:

- are you easy-going or hard work to interact with, and hence how will you fit in with the rest of the team?
- do you finish what you start, or get easily distracted?
- are you enthusiastic and motivated, or just in it for the steady wage?
- can you communicate clearly and articulately or do you grunt and nod?
- are you organised or scattered in your approach? do you plan in advance or react to problems as they arise?

This interview is a chance not just to answer their questions but look at the above areas and push them proactively.  So if they ask "tell me about your previous role" type questions, take the chance to say stuff like "That one really suited my organised approach to work, I was able to liaise with Jim the project manager to identify all the main priorities and tasks etc etc".

Do this subtly and you'll do well.  Non-subtle responses will seem like you're trying to play them - a very bad vibe to give off.

Be natural, friendly, enthusiastic, and above all honest (it shows when we're not, believe me!), and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen even, senior management can be quite techy in nature. They may give you an algo to write and you may be rejected if you cannot solve it. They may reject for the smallest flaw u may do. So take it as seriously as you have taken the other rounds.