# What happens if I started creating/closing DB connections in "JSP"?

Tags: java

I just happened to read this post :-

[Questions every good Java/Java EE Developer should be able to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-j2ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/2117595#2117595)

On this link there is one question by `Elister` :- `What happens if I started creating/closing DB connections in "JSP"?` I am not able to answer this. What would happen? Any disadvantages? And what would i do to prevent it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess he is expecting the answer to be layered architecure: specificaly MVC and DOA patterns