# Is there any way to create a class property in Python?

Tags: python, class, properties, class-method

The following doesn't work for some reason:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     @property
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls):
...             return "asdf"
... 
>>> foo.bar
<property object at 0x1da8d0>
>>> foo.bar + '\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'str'
```

Is there a way to do this, or is my only alternative to resort to some kind of metaclass trickery?

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with 'properties' in Python maybe this will help you understand what Jason is talking about http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the descriptor `property` to trigger when you get an attribute from object X, then you must put the descriptor in `type(X)`.  So if X is a class, the descriptor must go in the class's type, also known as the class's metaclass -- no "trickery" involved, it's just a matter of completely general rules.

Alternatively, you might write your own special-purpose descriptor.  See [here](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) for an excellent "how-to" treaty on descriptors.  **Edit** for example:

```
class classprop(object):
  def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = classmethod(f)
  def __get__(self, *a):
    return self.f.__get__(*a)()

class buh(object):
  @classprop
  def bah(cls): return 23

print buh.bah
```

emits `23`, as desired.

Comment: I'm using a metaclass elsewhere in the inheritance hierarchy, so if I use the metaclass, I get the following:  `metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

Comment: @Jason, you could also use a subclass of all involved metaclasses, as the error message says (few use multiple custom metaclasses, or metaclasses that don't subclass `type`, so probably you only need to subclass the one custom metaclass you're using) -- but if the custom descriptor does the job, it may indeed be a simpler approach.