# Why isn't this classprop implementation working?

Tags: python, class, properties, descriptor, class-method

Based on [a question I previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173206/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-class-property-in-python/2173321#2173321), I tried to come up with a class property that would allow setting as well as getting.  So I wrote this and put it in a module `util`:

```
class classprop(object):
    def __init__(self, fget, fset=None):
        if isinstance(fget, classmethod):
            self.fget = fget
        else:
            self.fget = classmethod(fget)
        if not fset or isinstance(fset, classmethod):
            self.fset = fset
        else:
            self.fset = classmethod(fset)
    def __get__(self, *a):
        return self.fget.__get__(*a)()
    def __set__(self, cls, value):
        print 'In __set__'
        if not self.fset:
            raise AttributeError, "can't set attribute"
        fset = self.fset.__get__(cls)
        fset(value)

class X(object):
    @classmethod
    def _get_x(cls):
        return 1
    @classmethod
    def _set_x(cls, value):
        print 'You set x to {0}'.format(value)
    x = classprop(fget=_get_x, fset=_set_x)
```

While getting is working, setting doesn't seem to be getting called:

```
>>> util.X.x
1
>>> util.X.x = 1
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

(And I have seen implementations of this that work a bit differently.  I'm specifically wanting to know why *this* implementation isn't working.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The doc's say:](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#implementing-descriptors)

> `object.__set__(self, instance,
>   value)` Called to set the attribute on
>   an instance *instance* of the owner
>   class to a new value, *value*.

Unlike for `__get__`, it does not mention *class attributes*. So Python won't call *any* `__set__` on a class attribute.

Comment: Why would `X` not be the instance and `type` be the class?

Comment: Instances and types are different and so is writing to them. Python just does not implement descriptors the way you want them to be.