# Class property using Python C-API

Tags: python, python-c-api

What is the best way to create *class properties* (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203286/how-to-create-a-read-only-class-property-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173206/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-class-property-in-python)) using the Python C-API? Static properties would also work in my case.

**Follow up:**

I tried to implement yak's suggestion. I defined a class `P` with get and set functions in its `tp_descr_get` and `tp_descr_set` slots. Then I added an instance of `P` to the dictionary of the type object for the class `X` under the key `p`. Then

```
x1 = X()
x2 = X()
x1.p = 10
print x1.p
print x2.p
print X.p
x2.p = 11
print x1.p
print x2.p
print X.p
```

works (first 10 is printed three times, then 11 is printed three times), but

```
X.p = 12
```

fails with the error message

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'X'
```

How do I fix that?

**Follow up 2:**

If I allocate the type object with `PyMem_Malloc` and set the `Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` flag, then everything works ; I can do `X.p = 12` with the expected result.

Things also work if I keep the type object in a static variable and set the `Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` flag, but that is obviously not a good idea. (But why does it matter whether the type object is in static or dynamic memory? I never let its reference count drop to 0 anyway.)

The restriction that you can only set attributes on dynamic types seems very strange. What is the rationale behind this?

**Follow up 3:**

No, it does not work. If I make the type `X` dynamic, then `X.p = 12` does not set the property `X.p` to twelve; it actually binds the object `12` to the name `X.p`. In other words, afterwards, `X.p` is not an integer-valued property but an integer.

**Follow up 4:**

Here is the C++ code for the extension:

```
#include <python.h>
#include <exception>

class ErrorAlreadySet : public std::exception {};

// P type ------------------------------------------------------------------

struct P : PyObject
{
    PyObject* value;
};

PyObject* P_get(P* self, PyObject* /*obj*/, PyObject* /*type*/)
{
    Py_XINCREF(self->value);
    return self->value;
}

int P_set(P* self, PyObject* /*obj*/, PyObject* value)
{
    Py_XDECREF(self->value);
    self->value = value;
    Py_XINCREF(self->value);
    return 0;
}

struct P_Type : PyTypeObject
{
    P_Type()
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
        ob_refcnt = 1;
        tp_name = "P";
        tp_basicsize = sizeof(P);
        tp_descr_get = (descrgetfunc)P_get;
        tp_descr_set = (descrsetfunc)P_set;
        tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT;

        if(PyType_Ready(this)) throw ErrorAlreadySet();
    }
};

PyTypeObject* P_type()
{
    static P_Type typeObj;
    return &typeObj;
}


// P singleton instance ----------------------------------------------------

P* createP()
{
    P* p_ = PyObject_New(P, P_type());
    p_->value = Py_None;
    Py_INCREF(p_->value);
    return p_;
}

P* p()
{
    static P* p_ = createP();
    Py_INCREF(p_);
    return p_;
}

PyObject* p_value()
{
    PyObject* p_ = p();
    PyObject* value = p()->value;
    Py_DECREF(p_);
    Py_INCREF(value);
    return value;
}


// X type ------------------------------------------------------------------

struct X : PyObject {};

void X_dealloc(PyObject* self)
{
    self->ob_type->tp_free(self);
}

struct X_Type : PyTypeObject
{
    X_Type()
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
        ob_refcnt = 1;
        tp_name = "M.X";
        tp_basicsize = sizeof(X);
        tp_dealloc = (destructor)X_dealloc;
        tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE;

        tp_dict = PyDict_New();
        PyObject* key = PyString_FromString("p");
        PyObject* value = p();
        PyDict_SetItem(tp_dict, key, value);
        Py_DECREF(key);
        Py_DECREF(value);

        if(PyType_Ready(this)) throw ErrorAlreadySet();
    }

    void* operator new(size_t n) { return PyMem_Malloc(n); }
    void operator delete(void* p) { PyMem_Free(p); }
};

PyTypeObject* X_type()
{
    static PyTypeObject* typeObj = new X_Type;
    return typeObj;
}

// module M ----------------------------------------------------------------

PyMethodDef methods[] = 
{
    {"p_value", (PyCFunction)p_value, METH_NOARGS, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initM(void)
{
    try {
        PyObject* m = Py_InitModule3("M", methods, 0);
        if(!m) return;
        PyModule_AddObject(m, "X", (PyObject*)X_type());
    }
    catch(const ErrorAlreadySet&) {}
}
```

This code defines a module `M` with a class `X` with a class property `p` as described before. I have also added a function `p_value()` that lets you directly inspect the object that implements the property.

Here is the script I have used to test the extension:

```
from M import X, p_value

x1 = X()
x2 = X()

x1.p = 1
print x1.p
print x2.p
print X.p
print p_value()
print

x2.p = 2
print x1.p
print x2.p
print X.p
print p_value()
print

X.p = 3
print x1.p
print x2.p
print X.p
print p_value()     # prints 2
print

x1.p = 4       # AttributeError: 'M.X' object attribute 'p' is read-only
```

Comment: Check this for an explanation by Guido: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/077167.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to these Python solutions, you will have to create a `classproperty` type in C and implement its `tp_descr_get` function (which corresponds to `__get__` in Python).

Then, if you want to use that in a C type, you would have to create an instance of your `classproperty` type and insert it into dictionary of your type (`tp_dict` slot of your type).

**Follow up:**

It would seem that it's impossible to set an attribute of a C type. The `tp_setattro` function of the metaclass (`PyType_Type`) raises a "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type" exception for all non-heap types (types with no `Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` flag). This flag is set for dynamic types. You could make your type dynamic but it might be more work then it's worth.

This means that the solution I gave initially allows you to create a property (as in: computed attribute) on a C type object with the limitation that it's read only. For setting you could use a class/static-method (`METH_CLASS`/`METH_STATIC` flag on a method in `tp_methods`).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it almost works; see the edited question.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using dynamic types and it works; see the edited question.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Turns out that `tp_descr_set` isn't called when a type attribute is set, it works only on instances. A workaround is to move the descriptor to metatype. Your type will be an instance of the metatype so descriptor will work. You would set the metatype as `ob_type` of `X`. All this applies to Python as well, see this (http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/set-method-is-not-called-for-class-attribute-access-td1014860.html) for example.

Comment: If getting/setting `p` on an instance of `X` rather than on the type itself is an option, then things become **much** simpler because you can use `tp_getset`.

Comment: Thanks! I have learnt a lot from doing this discussion. Now, I think I will just do the simplest solution: two class functions, a getter and a setter.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to convey the essence of what I've discovered about using class static properties.

My (edited) code is as follows:

```c
// Prepare your type object, which you will no doubt complete 
// by calling PyType_Ready, as here.
if (PyType_Ready(typeObj) < 0)
{
  return;
}

Py_INCREF(typeObj);
PyModule_AddObject(module, typeName, (PyObject*) typeObj);

// Now we add static members directly to the type's tp_dict, but 
// only *after* we've registered the type (above)
PyObject* dict = typeObj->tp_dict;

// You'll have your own wrapper / C values in the line below. This is just
// a pseudo-version of what I am (successfully) using.
PyObject* tmp = MyCreateWrapper(myStaticValueInC);

// Py_INCREF(tmp); // You may need this, depending on how line above works.

PyDict_SetItemString(dict, staticPropertyName, tmp);

Py_DECREF(tmp);
```

I believe all the essentials are here in terms of what order to construct your code in order to implement a class property.

Comment: Modifying tp_dict in this way [appears to be prohibited](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict):
"Warning It is not safe to use PyDict_SetItem() on or otherwise modify tp_dict with the dictionary C-API."

Answer (score 1):

If that is an acceptable solution, you may create a method on the module holding the declaration of `X`, that simply sets the class variable as you wish. For example:

```
PyObject* set_p_value(PyObject*, PyObject* o) {
  if(PyDict_SetItemString(X_type()->tp_dict, "p", o) == -1) return 0;
  Py_RETURN_NONE; 
}

PyMethodDef methods[] = 
{
    ...
    {"set_p_value", (PyCFunction)set_p_value, METH_O, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Once that is there, than:

```
from M import X, set_p_value
set_p_value(3)
print X.p #should print '3'
```

Should work as expected. A draw-back is that, unfortunately, this functionality is unrelated to the type object itself. This could be partially circumvented if you provided a class method that sets the class variable as you wish.

Comment: Modifying tp_dict in this way [appears to be prohibited](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict):
"Warning It is not safe to use PyDict_SetItem() on or otherwise modify tp_dict with the dictionary C-API."

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to `tp_dict` as long as it happens before you call `PyType_Ready`:

```c
int err;
PyObject *p;

if (!X_Type.tp_dict) {
    X_Type.tp_dict = PyDict_New();
    if (!X_Type.tp_dict)
        return NULL;
}

p = PyLong_FromLong(12);
if (!p)
    return NULL;

err = PyDict_SetItemString(X_Type.tp_dict, "p", p)
Py_DECREF(p);
if (err)
    return NULL;

m = PyModule_Create(&M_module);
if (!m)
    return NULL;

if (PyModule_AddType(m, &X_type));
    return NULL;

return m;
```