# Ignoring GEM because its extensions are not built

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chruby

On both my work and home computers, I recently upgraded Ruby to 2.3.1, using `ruby-install`. I use `chruby` as my Ruby switcher.

I started seeing this warning in my terminal:

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
Ignoring byebug-5.0.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 5.0.0
Ignoring concurrent-ruby-ext-1.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine concurrent-ruby-ext --version 1.0.2
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
```

On my work, computer, the list was much longer, but easy to resolve. When I tried the suggested `gem pristine GEM`, it told me it couldn't find the gem, so I ran `gem install GEM`, and that solved it.

At home, nothing is working.

Things I have tried, from common sense and various other Stack questions:

- `gem pristine GEM`
- `gem pristine --all`
- uninstalling and reinstalling the gem
- `gem update`
- `gem update --system`
- `bundle update`
- uninstalling and reinstalling `bundler`
- uninstalling and reinstalling `rails` (Though, it's not a Rails specific problem.)
- deleting `~/.bundle/`
- opening `XCode` and letting it install some extensions (It did need to do it, but it didn't fix anything.)
- running `brew doctor` and solving all the minor issues, then `brew update` and `brew upgrade`
- `gem install curb` (I can't imagine what this gem has to do with this issue, but two different people listed it as the last step of their fix to the same warning.)

Comment: I am even seeing the same warning if the gems are not installed. I uninstalled `bcrypt` and it still gave me two warnings about it.

Comment: did you update bundler?  uninstalling and reinstalling will just use whatever is in your Gemfile.lock.  Bundler is the one who will build the extensions.  Also, your output is listing multiple versions of gems so you should know this is system wide for that version of ruby (meaning you'll have multiple gems to rebuild).

Comment: I was in my home folder, not a Rails project, so there was no Gemfile.

Comment: Same issue happened to me (using rvm). `gem pristine --all` did not work.  Solved by deleting all gems including bundler.  Then installed bundler `gem install bundler` and finally navigated back to my project and ran `bundle install` which reinstalled all my gems and everything is working

Comment: In my case, it was caused by a vim extension. I did alias vim="rvm use system do vim" to work around it. But I only saw the warning when I exited vim so if you are seeing it in other situations this probably won't apply.

Comment: @PhillipLongman, did you have this issue on macOS?

Comment: @kelin Yes, although I would expect/guess this could happen on any OS.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

I came across this exact issue today - getting warnings like this for gems that weren't even installed!

... Well, it turns out the gems *were* installed - for a different ruby than the one I had set active with chruby (2.2.3 vs 2.3.1).

Switching to all the different rubies and running `gem pristine --all` on all of them solved the problem.

Comment: This worked for me doing this only on the current ruby (I use rvm). Maybe this prevents someone from doing too much cleanup ;)

Comment: Sometimes `gem pristine --all` will do no good. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167377/79496) on Ask Different for more info.

Comment: if `gem pristine --all` has permission issues, you should check `which ruby`. `brew link --overwrite ruby && source ~/.bash_profile` and run `gem pristine --all` may help

Comment: None of those solutions are working for me and I have this same issue.

Comment: gem pristine --all put me into several toubles, I strongly recommend not to use it without care

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the warnings it's faster to reinstall everything. `gem pristine --all` is very slow.

Comment: Note to self - also see this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436672/79496

Comment: How did you switch between all the different rubies and run gem pristine --all ?

Comment: AleGiovane, I think the source of your issue laid elsewhere, because `gem pristine` is a pretty basic and safe thing to do when encountering weird issues.

Comment: Asad, you use whatever setup you usually use to manage your Ruby versions. I currently use `asdf version manager`, because it handles all the languages I need in one program. RVM is a similar version manager, for Ruby only, which is popular enough that lots of Rubyists don't realize there's anything else. When I wrote this post, I was using a barebones approach, installing versions with `ruby-install` and switching between them with `chruby`.

Answer (score 36):

I ran into this issue and followed all the same commands as above, even going so far as to remove all my previously installed Ruby versions. However, the error persisted.

Turns out, there were some leftover gems for the various (previously uninstalled) versions in `~/.gem/ruby/`. After removing the folders I no longer used, the errors disappeared.

Comment: This did it for me. rm -rf. I'd previously tried to pristine install all of my gems to no avail.

Comment: This fixed it for me too after switching to `asdf` from `ruby-install` & `chruby`

Comment: this fixed `sudo rm -rf ~/.gem/ruby/`

Comment: Removing the `cache` folder under `~/.gem/ruby/` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 16):

I've had this problem today too and it frustrated because I couldn't type because my whole editor flashed red with error messages.

I'm not entirely sure what exactly caused it but I believe it's **because we have multiple ruby versions OR multiple ruby version managers** **installed** and they overwrite each other and otherwise mess up your paths towards the gems.

The `gem` command also gets overwritten when you have rbenv and rvm.

See which ones you've installed by typing;

```
which rvm
which rbenv
which chruby
```

If one of those is installed it'll return a path. Then delete them, make sure to completely clean out all the directories and start with a clean install.

---

**Remove**

Here's what I did for **rvm**;

```
rvm implode
gem uninstall rvm
rm -rf ~/.rvm
rm -rf ~/.rvmrc
```

Here's what I did for **rbenv**

First installed https://github.com/meowsus/rbenv-clean, then

```
rbenv clean
sudo apt-get remove rbenv
rm -rf ~/.rbenv
```

**Reinstall**

Then you have a clean home directory to work from. I reïnstalled rbenv with [How to install Ruby 2.1.4 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595620/how-to-install-ruby-2-1-4-on-ubuntu-14-04). And finally;

```
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: Just removing the rvm related stuff fixed this problem for me on macOS

Comment: This solved my problem with msfconsole (aka metasploit)

Answer (score 15):

In my case the warning itself has suggested the solution , so I just run them one by one.

```
Ignoring bigdecimal-2.0.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 2.0.0
Ignoring date-3.0.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine date --version 3.0.1
Ignoring dbm-1.1.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine dbm --version 1.1.0
Ignoring etc-1.1.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine etc --version 1.1.0
```

Here an example:

```
gem pristine bigdecimal --version 2.0.0
```

so running the command of each line has solved my problem.

Comment: Awesome, i just needed to open my eyes 

Comment: works finally!!

Answer (score 14):

I did everything mentioned above including

- xcode-select --install
- reinstall ruby
- reinstall all gems
- gem pristine --all

but the issue was the same for me.
I just rebooted my Mac as the last hope, and the warning messages are disappeared.

Weird, but if anyone's struggling with this issue after trying everything on StackOverflow, try reboot your machine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reboot tip. I had the same problem, on a Mac, and was able to resolve just by starting a new terminal session.

Answer (score 9):

Running `gem pristine --all` didn't help at first, but then I realized: the script I was running began with the line:

`#!/usr/bin/ruby`

On my macOS system (Catalina, but I don't think it matters), this points to the Ruby that came with the system, not the one installed by RVM. Running `gem pristine --all` was fixing up the RVM installation, but my script was calling a different version of Ruby.

The fix for me was to use the `env` command to call whichever Ruby is specified in the current shell's `PATH`. Changing the top line of the script to this fixed it:

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Comment: Just happened to me – thanks! It means that `bundle install` installed the gems (and their native extensions) for a the ruby selected via the RVM Ruby switcher, where a script referring to the system Ruby cannot find them. Your solution is the standard practice to make Ruby scripts and gems work with user installed rubies ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11495983)).

Comment: This put me on the right track! In my case, I wanted tmuxinator to be a util (not a bundled dep for a specific project), so I apt installed it on Ubuntu. So doing `apt purge tmuxinator` and then `gem install tmuxinator` made it work. I'll probably have to gem install it whenever I upgrade my non-project ruby version, but I like this better. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this thrice. Solved it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Adding my own flavor here. I use `rbenv` installed via Homebrew and was getting four of these "ignoring... extensions not built" messages. Specifically:

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.12 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.12
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring bootsnap-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.2
Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
```

I tried many things in this thread with no luck. Finally in my case I did:

- `brew uninstall rbenv`
- `rm -rf ~/.rbenv`
- `brew install rbenv`

At this point I was still getting the errors, but now I had only a single Ruby version to contend with:

```
$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/will/.rbenv/version)
```

At this point I tried `sudo gem pristine --all` but was rejected for permissions on the system Gems directory.

So I went through and ran pristine on each gem, like

`sudo gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.12` (etc)

And finally the errors were gone.

Comment: Fantastic, that saved my day!
I tried everything else mentioned before your answer, and it did not work. Only your procedure made it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR - Ruby gems don't like Rubies running from symlinks or moved from where they were built (because of embedded shebangs)

If the Ruby directory is invoked or environment vars point to a symlink'ed directory, or are copied or renamed, this message is likely.  I am using chruby and was symlinking `/opt/rubies/` -> `/usr/local/ruby/`, but Ruby's dynamic library-finding logic doesn't play well with this.

The solution in my case was to replace the symlink with actual rubies in `/opt/rubies/` and run `gem pristine --all` in each Ruby. For others using RVM or Rbenv, good luck with that without starting over from scratch.

This may not be your exact issue, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: It turned out to be the running `gem pristine --all` on all of them part. Thanks for resurrecting this dead question. I was close to just burning it all down and starting over.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed RVM, possible you're catching the error because you have installed different versions.

Check and remove useless versions,
but I think this is **not good** approach.
Anyway errors gone.

```
rvm list
rvm use ruby-version
rvm remove ruby-useless-version
```

After refresh cocoapods, it should be injected in .rvm GEM_HOME

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem install cocoapods
```

Probably `pod COMMAND` will throw the error about `minitest` gem, so – `gem install minitest`

Answer (score 4):

Running Mac OS Catalina, brew and rbenv ...

Having come across this exact problem today, and gone through all the answers here I eventually stumbled across another reason for this error:

`Ignoring nokogiri 1.10.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.7`

And of course gem pristine did no work.

My problem was a hard coded GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH environment variables which were overriding rbenv.

So, check that you haven't set GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME in ~/.zshrc

Comment: Yup, was my issue also!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but I just came across this issue myself.

You don't need to restart your machine, you just need to refresh your environment, you can do this with the rehash command:

```csh
rehash
```

From the man page: `rehash command re-computes the internal hash table of the contents of directories listed in the path environmental variable to account for new commands added.`

Comment: What OS are you talking about?

Comment: `rehash` or `hash -r` for bash is a shell command available on *nix. When the C shell starts, it builds a hash table of all the commands in its path: each command name and its absolute pathname. So, after you start a csh running, if new programs are added to directories along the path, you need to use the shell's rehash command to rebuild its hash table. (cf: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch27_06.htm)

Comment: THIS! The point is that even with `rbenv` I had this issue but I forgot using `rbenv rehash` so the internals were still pointing to the system Ruby (macos) instead of the fresh installed one... so much for reading ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is also a problem when you're developing on Mac and then build a Docker image:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=879802&tstart=0

> When you do a "bundle install --deployment", bundler will create a
>   vendor directory w/ your gems in it.  Note that whilst this includes
>   your gems in the local folder, it will only include the native
>   extensions for your platform. As you're on macOS this will be Darwin.
>   You'll need to do repeat the process on a 64-bit x86 linux
>   environment.

Answer (score 3):

Most comments here are on the right track. This problem often occurs after a Ruby version upgrade. I reviewed the **gem** command code and here is the gist of it.

Extensions are compiled into the gems/*gem*/ext subdirectory of the gems home directory. For example, on my Cygwin installation (and similarly under Raspbian), the BigDecimal extension is compiled into
/usr/share/gems/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.5/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.so.

However, this is **not** where the extension is referenced when executed - that is from
/usr/lib/gems/ruby/*ver*/*gem*. Again using BigDecimal, the extension file when executed is loaded from
/usr/lib/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bigdecimal-1.3.5/bigdecimal.so

Here is the key: in this same directory, there is an empty tag file
/usr/lib/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bigdecimal-1.3.5/gem.build_complete

When the **gem** command starts up, it refers to the gems/specifications directory to get a list of installed gems and information as to whether they have extensions. If a gem does have extensions, **gem** (among other sanity checks) looks for the tag file gem.build_complete. If that is not found, it emits the error message "Ignoring *gem* because its extensions are not built".

Any action which rebuilds all extensions will fix this problem. Or, as total hack, if you in a hurry and brave, you can try copying all contents of /usr/lib/gems/ruby/*oldver* to /usr/lib/gems/ruby/*newver* e.g.

```
cd /usr/lib/gems/ruby
cp -nv 2.3.0/* 2.6
```

Answer (score 2):

[Libby's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built/53383975#comment84253101_40361765) to just start a new terminal session (which she commented on Sebastian Kim's answer) worked for me. Much quicker than any of the others too so I wanted to make it an answer so it was more visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but only when I was starting `tmux` session using `tmuxinator`.

Turned out it's because I'm using `tmuxinator` from `brew` instead of installing it using `gem install`. Maybe using `chruby` at the same time contributed to the problem as well.

p/s: I also removed unused ruby from `~/.gem/ruby` but I doubt that's the reason this issue was resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall of Vagrant also works. There's an `unistall.tool` bash script included in the installer .dmg image that will remove Vagrant.

Found this solution here: [Updating Vagrant and Gems Extentions Not Built In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891428/updating-vagrant-and-gems-extentions-not-built-in)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I'm using rbenv.  For some reason my global rbenv setting went missing.  In order to fix this problem I set the global version to one of my rbenv versions... for instance:

rbenv global 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

On my case I was trying to run `pristine --all` but I was getting:

```
Ignoring ffi-1.11.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.11.1
Ignoring jaro_winkler-1.5.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine jaro_winkler --version 1.5.3
Ignoring psych-3.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych --version 3.1.0
/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': incompatible library version - /.gem/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.bundle (fatal)
```

Then, I deleted the content on `Users/{{user.name}}⁩/⁨.gem⁩` then as I needed to run `bundle install --force`, it reinstalled everything, then the command `pristine --all` worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me for **RubyMine** IntelliJ

I had two different terminals being used and `RVM` and `ruby<Version>`.

**Solution:**

I had to switch it to the RVM version for the errors to go away in `Preferences>Languages&Frameworks>Ruby SDK`

**Errors:**

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.0 rubymine

Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `rvm` like me, the **fix could a simple**:

```sh
rvm get stable
rvm reload
```

As stated in this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192513

Answer (score 0):

I have executed these commands in Terminal and worked for me:

1. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. `brew install ruby`, it may need sudo (sudo brew install ruby).
3. `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
4. `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. `sudo gem pristine --all`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu this worked for me.

1. `source ~/.bash_profile`
2. `sudo gem pristine --all`

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across [it](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_2/lib/rubygems/basic_specification.rb#L79-L80) while running ruby 2.6 under `docker` with gems installed with ruby 2.7. It appears in 2.7.0 the extension dir changed (`$GEM_HOME/extensions/x86_64-linux` -> `$GEM_HOME/extensions/x86_64-linux-musl`). As such ruby 2.6 couldn't find the installed extensions.

In my case I simply had to run the correct ruby version.

If that's not your case, `bundle pristine` won't help, since gems without their extensions are [not considered installed](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v3.4.19/bundler/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb#L372).

You can follow the ruby's advice and do `gem pristine GEM --version VERSION`. But that will leave the old extensions dir. Which is probably not a big deal, but if you want to avoid that... If you're running the `ruby` (`docker`) image, you can delete `$GEM_HOME` (`/usr/local/bundle`) and reinstall all the gems.

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/df54d169a4955833195bd7ba75b6549a).

Answer (score 0):

After I run command **brew install cocoapods**, I was getting this error

```
Ignoring ffi-1.16.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
```

I have tried a lot of commands, nothing helped.
Then I run

- **brew uninstall cocoapods**
- **bundle install**
- **gem install cocoapods**
- **pod install**

And it is installing now without above error.