# Updating Vagrant and Gems Extentions Not Built In

Tags: vagrant

Should I be concerned with the gems for running vagrant?

```
➜  ~ vagrant version
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
Installed Version: 1.9.0
Latest Version: 1.8.7

You're running an up-to-date version of Vagrant!
➜  ~ gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["nokogiri"] = 1.6.3.1
➜  ~ gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["nokogiri"] = 1.6.3.1
```

Comment: can you try to run `vagrant plugin repair`

Comment: Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.3.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this after upgrading to MacOS 10.2.2 and Vagrant 1.9.1. I'm not sure which caused this issue.

Based on info at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/z6GX-3Qn3ZM I used the uninstaller script and then re-installed Vagrant and I stopped seeing these 2 lines.