# How to package local gems to be used on different Linux host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am getting this message while doing `bundle package`:

```
Ignoring PriorityQueue-0.1.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine PriorityQueue --version 0.1.2
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.18
Ignoring ibm_db-3.0.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ibm_db --version 3.0.1
Ignoring json-1.8.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.6
Ignoring kgio-2.11.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine kgio --version 2.11.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.7.0.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.7.0.1
Ignoring raindrops-0.17.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine raindrops --version 0.17.0
Ignoring therubyracer-0.12.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine therubyracer --version 0.12.3
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.2
Ignoring unicorn-5.2.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unicorn --version 5.2.0
```

I am trying to package my gems that have been used in my application, so that I can use it on another system without downloading the gems again, but I am getting the above errors on that system.

Comment: Are you using rvm/rbenv or the system's ruby?

Comment: I am using rvm to install ruby. After that i am running bundle package on one system and then taking the complete application folder on another system to run it without internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may have gems installed for a different installed version of ruby. Certain gems are linked to system libraries *(read: in C code)* that need to be built and are just wrappers around the actual C-code library which is the case for bcrypt or nokogiri for instance.

Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39866401/14533) in a different post, it may be the same issue, basically running:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Should fix the problem

Comment: You save my day.