# fatal: incompatible library version - /Users/xxx/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext.bundle

Tags: ruby, vim, rubygems

recently I'm so confused to got this error! I don't know why and how I had this error, maybe it's because I had update my mac system to High Sierra several days ago. But everything seems ok when I finished this update until I typed ***vim/vi*** command in the terminal. Here is details:

[image]

[image]

First, I had "try" by the suggestions, however, it never worked. And then, I had googled and been told it's maybe the ***command-t*** problem, so I had do sth. like this:

[image]

Or close and reopen the terminal again, the problem still exists. Someone said it's the ***ruby version*** problem caused this, that means the system-ruby version conflict with the vim supported ruby version (hope I understand correctly), so I had uninstalled ruby by rvm and installed the 2.3 version according to the system-framework required:

[image]

However, the problem still...And last, I think it's maybe the rubygems problem, so I had uninstalled the "problem gem that need pristine" and reinstalled again, or just do "gem pristine --all" that suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built) seems similar question. Unfortunately...

Finally, I'm suggested to uninstalled the rubygems and reinstalled again, however, I don't want to do this. Because you know, I had many gems installed, and a lot of projects need its support, I can't make the venture right now.

So, I need a good solution!

Comment: It's hard to suggest you a solution since the problem is probably unique to your local system. The simplest solution I would suggest is to just remove the command-t plugin to get rid of ruby dependency and use some other fuzzy finder, see, for example, here - https://vimawesome.com/?q=tag:fuzzy

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems solved in this way:

```
cd ./vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext.bundle
rvm use system && make clean && ruby extconf.rb && make
```

And the suggestions comes from [here](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/254), however, it's just a temporary method (open a new terminal window, the problem still exists) and just solved the ***vim*** problem, helpless for ***vi*** when I'm trying to open a file with the command.

Anyway, just like @Boris Serebrov said this problem depends on my unique local system, so it's really hard to make a good suggestion. I'll try to fix this by making an adjustment of my system, thanks anyway!