# Ignoring gems because its extensions are not built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

I installed the rails in my machine

ruby 2.3.1

rails 5.1.4

Ubuntu 16.04 os

After rails installation, When i check rails version `rails -v`
It throws Ignoring "Some gems list" because its extensions are not built

```
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.1
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring byebug-9.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.1.0
Ignoring curb-0.9.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.9.4
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.18
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring nio4r-2.2.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.2.0
Ignoring pg-0.21.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.21.0
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.5
Rails 5.1.4
```

After new rails application created successfully
When i run `bundle install` 
It throws errror message like:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Try to 
1 ) `gem install json -v '1.8.6'`
2) `gem update bundler` after `bundle install`

Comment: @mayur shahI give 'gem update bundler'  'Updating installed gems
Nothing to update' after throws same erro

Comment: it's not updating installed gems but Install a newer version of bundler.

Comment: did you set your ruby version with rvm ?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built

Comment: @Vishal yes bro

Comment: What is putput when you run `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` ?

Comment: @fool-dev sorry bro, i can't seen but now I solved, Thanks

Comment: `--all` didn't help me, but a specific `sudo gem pristine ffi` did help

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I ran the command `gem pristine --all` to remove all errors

This error occurs when you switch the ruby version

Comment: Not work for me(

Comment: It might take a looong time to go through all the versions of all the gems.

Comment: After upgrading to Mojave, I had to use sudo and go through each specified gem. Above did not work in my case. Also reinstalled ruby.

Comment: If affected gems list is short you may also just run ```gem pristine gem_name_here``` for each one

Comment: this will not work monterey.

Comment: Didn't worked for me either.