# I installed rails 6 beta, but I can't start my sample application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed rails 6 beta and I used rvm also.

gem install rails --pre

My Gemfile has:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.beta1'
```

When I try and run the rails using:

```
rails s
```

I get this error:

> Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem
>   pristine bindex --version 0.5.0 Ignoring bootsnap-1.4.0 because its
>   extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.4.0
>   Ignoring byebug-11.0.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem
>   pristine byebug --version 11.0.0 Rails is not currently installed on
>   this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install rails
> ```
>
> You can then rerun your "rails" command.

I already installed rails, so not sure why I am seeing this error?

Comment: did you run bundle install? Also, please check the rails version from your console `rails -v`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built) help?

Answer (score 0):

The bundler of your current ruby version has an older version of rails installed.

So make these steps:

- Check your current ruby version (`ruby -v`) and if its working together with rails 6 (requires ruby 2.5.0 or higher)
- Install the new bundler in the ruby version (`gem install bundler`)
- Install explicit rails 6 (for the ruby version with the new bundler) `gem install rails`
- Run `bundle install`
- Retry starting the server `rails s`

PS: If you want more than one ruby version on your system you should use rbenv or use Docker for the development.

Question: Your sudo command really needed? So your ruby is only accessible as root user? You overthink it :)

Comment: I'm using rvm for this