# Flutter Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

When i  try to build **Flutter project** to **IOS** it show me this error, I have tried to clean and also tried to change the directory of the project.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode... Running pod install... CocoaPods' output: ↳

    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Specifying multiple `post_install` hooks is unsupported..

     #  from /Users/eapple/Downloads/codecanyon-IRJuYEQd-delivery-boy-for-multirestaurants-flutter-app/flutter_application/ios/Podfile:43
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #  
     >  post_install do |installer|
     #    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     #  -------------------------------------------

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:301:in `rescue in block in from_ruby'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:295:in `block in from_ruby'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in `from_ruby'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:259:in `from_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:200:in `podfile'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:150:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods: ↳
    Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Here is the **pubspec.yaml** file

```
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
  google_maps_flutter: 0.5.27
  mvc_pattern: 5.1.1
  global_configuration: 1.5.0
  http: 0.12.1
  html: 0.14.0+3
  shared_preferences: 0.5.7
  flutter_html: 0.11.1
  location: 3.0.2
  url_launcher: 5.4.5
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.13
  cached_network_image: 2.2.0
  fluttertoast: 4.0.1
```

**Things I have tried, from common sense and various other Stack questions:**

- `flutter clean`
- Adding this to `ios/Podfile`

  ```
  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
         end
       end
    end
  ```
- `flutter pub get`
- installing `gem install ffi --version 1.13.1 --user-install`

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/. You need to stop using the system ruby and install your own.

Comment: Hi Umer, have you tried uncommenting the line platform: iOS, '9.0' on your Podfile

Comment: Yes i tried but it arise new error

Comment: use CocoaPods and gem install ffi again

Answer (score 2):

Update: you might not need to do this anymore, depending on the version you're working on if you have this issue follow the next steps but you might be in a better position just following the installation process from the official website.

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

Old solution:
On the Flutter official site when installing flutter they tell you to run this command if you're using apple sillicon.

Deprecated: the website doesn't include this note anymore.
[image]

```
$ sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

You could also delete your ios/Podfile and ios/Podfile.lock

then run

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run
```

just remember to connect your device or run it on the simulator open.

Comment: if it keeps getting error check your dependencies you probably have an incompatible dependency on your `pubspeck.yaml`, that's why you must check which message does it tell you after the command `flutter run` is executed it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest try running `gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2` as mentioned in the logs and see if it works. This issue seems to be similar to this [existing Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built).

Answer (score 0):

if your computer is using M1 or M2 processors then I suggest you try the following:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```