ROR + While running server start command or rubocop command getting Ignoring because its extensions are not built
❯ rubocop or rails s
Ignoring racc-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.0
Ignoring racc-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.0
... 93 times
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.18 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.18
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring puma-5.6.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine puma --version 5.6.4
Ignoring racc-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.0
Ignoring redcarpet-3.5.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine redcarpet --version 3.5.1
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.5


Every time the complete terminal is filled with an above error message & always takes lots of time to run while running any command.

make sure you are running the expected version of ruby for your application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built

Yes, the ruby version is correct in fact only one version was installed ie 2.5.3
