'bundle exec pod install' complains about json gem not being installed, even after 'bundle install'
After running a bundle install the json 2.5.1 gem seems to be installed
...
Fetching json 2.5.1
Installing json 2.5.1 with native extensions
...

Full output:
Ignoring curb-0.9.10 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.9.10
Ignoring digest-crc-0.6.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine digest-crc --version 0.6.3
Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3
Ignoring ffi-1.15.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
Ignoring json-2.5.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.5.1
Ignoring json-2.3.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.3.0
Ignoring json-2.2.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.2.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.9
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.4
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.7
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.6
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake 13.0.3
Using CFPropertyList 3.0.3
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using activesupport 5.2.6
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using httpclient 2.8.3
Fetching json 2.5.1
Installing json 2.5.1 with native extensions
Using algoliasearch 1.27.5
Using artifactory 3.0.15
Using atomos 0.1.3
Using aws-eventstream 1.1.1
Using aws-partitions 1.466.0
Using aws-sigv4 1.2.3
Using jmespath 1.4.0
Using aws-sdk-core 3.114.2
Using aws-sdk-kms 1.43.0
Using aws-sdk-s3 1.96.0
Using babosa 1.0.4
Using fastimage 2.2.4
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using colored 1.2
Using highline 2.0.3
Using commander 4.6.0
Using dotenv 2.7.6
Using emoji_regex 3.2.2
Using excon 0.82.0
Using faraday-em_http 1.0.0
Using faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.1.0
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.4
Using faraday 1.4.2
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.7 with native extensions
Using unf 0.1.4
Using domain_name 0.5.20190701
Using http-cookie 1.0.4
Using faraday-cookie_jar 0.0.7
Using faraday_middleware 1.0.0
Using gh_inspector 1.1.3
Using jwt 2.2.3
Using memoist 0.16.2
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using os 1.1.1
Using signet 0.15.0
Using googleauth 0.16.2
Using mini_mime 1.1.0
Using declarative 0.0.20
Using trailblazer-option 0.1.1
Using uber 0.1.0
Using representable 3.1.1
Using retriable 3.1.2
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using webrick 1.7.0
Using google-apis-core 0.3.0
Using google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 0.5.0
Using google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 0.3.0
Fetching digest-crc 0.6.3
Installing digest-crc 0.6.3 with native extensions
Using google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 0.4.0
Using google-apis-storage_v1 0.4.0
Using google-cloud-env 1.5.0
Using google-cloud-errors 1.1.0
Using google-cloud-core 1.6.0
Using google-cloud-storage 1.31.1
Using mini_magick 4.11.0
Using naturally 2.2.1
Using plist 3.6.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using security 0.1.3
Using simctl 1.6.8
Using terminal-notifier 2.0.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using tty-screen 0.8.1
Using tty-cursor 0.7.1
Using tty-spinner 0.9.3
Using word_wrap 1.0.0
Using claide 1.0.3
Using colored2 3.1.2
Using nanaimo 0.3.0
Using xcodeproj 1.19.0
Using rouge 2.0.7
Using xcpretty 0.3.0
Using xcpretty-travis-formatter 1.0.1
Using fastlane 2.185.0
Using badge 0.13.0
Using builder 3.2.4
Using clamp 1.3.2
Using fuzzy_match 2.0.4
Using nap 1.1.0
Using netrc 0.11.0
Fetching ffi 1.15.1
Installing ffi 1.15.1 with native extensions
Using ethon 0.14.0
Using typhoeus 1.4.0
Using cocoapods-core 1.10.1
Using cocoapods-deintegrate 1.0.4
Using cocoapods-downloader 1.4.0
Using cocoapods-plugins 1.0.0
Using cocoapods-search 1.0.0
Using cocoapods-trunk 1.5.0
Using cocoapods-try 1.2.0
Using escape 0.0.4
Using fourflusher 2.3.1
Using molinillo 0.6.6
Using ruby-macho 1.4.0
Using cocoapods 1.10.1
Using liquid 3.0.6
Using gyro 1.5.0
Using mini_portile2 2.5.3
Using net 0.3.3
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.11.7 (x86_64-darwin)
Using poesie 1.5.2
Using slather 2.7.1
Using xcode-install 2.7.0
Bundle complete! 7 Gemfile dependencies, 121 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

But when I run the bundle exec pod install command, bundler complains that json gem is missing.
Could not find json-2.5.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I don't know if it's important but each time I run the bundle install command, some gems (json, unf_ext, digest-crc, ffi) are always fetched and installed.
Thanks for your help.
I tried to resolve dependencies with bundle install before running the bundle exec command.

I think the interesting part is Ignoring json-2.3.0 because its extensions are not built. (and all the versions, as there are multiple ones) which lead to this one question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797458/ignoring-gem-because-its-extensions-are-not-built might worth a look...
