# Can't locate object method "new" via package "www::Mechanize" (perhaps you forgo t to load "www::Mechanize"?) at gmail.pl line 9, <stdin> line 2

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

i am very new to Perl however i was bit expertise in using perl modules i have worked on HTML::table extract but when i dealing with Mechanize module its keep saying me that CAN'T Locate object method "new" via package" while running the below program

```
    #!user/Perl/bin;
                 use strict;
                 use warnings;
                 use WWW::Mechanize;
                 my $URL ="https://accounts.google.com"   
                 my $username = <>;
                 my $password = <>;
                 my $mech =new  www::Mechanize();
                 $mech -> get($url);
$mech -> form_name('formname');
$mech -> field ('username' =>$username);
$mech -> field ('password' =>$password);
$mech -> click('signin');
```

i also been to some of guide lines given by stack overflow members and installed Mechanize::Firefox as well by following below steps

```
cpan WWW::Mechanize::Firefox
cpan MozRepl
cpan MozRepl::RemoteObject
```

however i keep getting the same error while running my code

please help me here..

Thanks
N@veen

Comment: As a side note: [How to do the shebang line right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791954/what-should-i-use-for-a-perl-scripts-shebang-line)

Answer (score 10):

Perl is case-sensitive. `www::Mechanize` is not the same as `WWW::Mechanize` (the latter has capital W's).

You're loading (upper-case) `WWW::Mechanize` and then trying to create an object of class (lower-case) `www::Mechanize`, which doesn't exist.

Also, it's generally considered best to avoid indirect-object syntax.  That is, use

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
```

instead of

```
my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize();
```

(But that wasn't the cause of your problem.)

Comment: I appreciate your help now i can able to run my script . just wanted to know about follow_link() what it will do exactly