# DBI installation on perl 5.10.0 MacOS 10.6.8

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm trying to install program called OrthoMCL on MacOS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. For it's work it needs DBI module for Perl. On my machine I have two perl installations - prebuild 5.10.0 version on /usr/bin/perl (call it Perl1) and 5.12.3 MacPorts installation (call it Perl2) which I actually use.

Problem is that OrthoMCL is trying to work with /usr/bin/perl. If I try to install CPAN DBI and DBD::mysql modules from CPAN for Perl1 I have errors like:

```
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccOBwzHU.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [Perl.o] Error 2
```

External compilation with

```
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL
make
```

results the same error.

I can install DBI and DBD::mysql on Perl2, but OrthoMCL doesn't work with it.

Addition Perl2 modules pathways to PERL5LIB variable does error with attempt to work with Perl1:

```
Perl lib version (5.12.4) doesn't match executable version (v5.10.0) at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm line 50.
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there an idea how can I install DBI and DBD::mysql modules for Perl1.
2. Does anybody know how can I force OrthoMCL to work with Perl2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL && make`.

Regarding perl version, you need to install the modules for your second perl version too for it to work. I don't know of `OrthoMCL` at all, but I'd consult it's documentation regarding how it works together with perl.

Comment: DBI and DBD::mysql are installed for my second perl version. I've tried your suggestion - everything the same both for DBI and DBD::mysql modules.

Comment: I am curious - why should `sudo` help here? Normally `perl Makefile.PL` and `make` shouldn't be run as root.

Comment: I'm thinking the make problems may be write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, I would strongly recommend never using the system perl at all, and instead using [App::Perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew/) to install and use a perl in your home directory.

For more than a few years, OS X's perl has been broken in various ways that are nearly impossible to fix unless you are a guru. It's a rathole you don't want to go down.

Perl applications should not be hardcoding /usr/bin/perl on their first ("shebang") line: that is a bug. Replace it with [/usr/bin/env perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792076/420444), which will run whichever perl you've selected with perlbrew.

Comment: I use MacPorts perl installation in my work. OrthoMCL is distributed as binary executives and I can't find source code, so I can't change application code. If you mean that I can influence application by something else, please explain.