# shebang/hashbang, (that is, "#!") at the beginning of a script

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, shell

**shebang/hashbang**, (that is, "#!") at the beginning of a script is an **interpreter directive**. This line tells the operating system what interpreter to invoke to run the script.

```
#!path/to/script
```

example:

```
which perl
perl is /opt/local/bin/perl
```

On my system perl is installed at above path, but not necessary, every system will have same path. Many time path varies from system to system, how do make it a generic one, so that I will not have to change the first line every time differing with machine to machine.

Comment: How about `#!/usr/bin/env perl`? At least that is suggested in [What should I use for a Perl script's shebang line?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2792076)

Comment: is this generic to all scripts(Perl, Python, bash, tcsh, awk etc)? If Yes, then YES, i am looking for the same.

Comment: It is more or less generic; you write the command you want to run after `#!/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Why is it more or less generic, and how does it work?

Comment: It is generic if you don't consider changing `python` to `perl` to `tcl` to `awk` as making it not-quite-generic.  You need to get the name after `/usr/bin/env` right — that stops it being generic.  However, the use of `#!/usr/bin/env` is as portable as it gets.  How does it work?  The [`env`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) command has a number of uses.  It can print the environment, modify the environment before running a command, or it can simply run a command without modifying the environment — but the command is found on `$PATH`, which is the key point.

Comment: Agreed!! Thanks many!!