# Perl runtime bug in OGS HPC cluster

Tags: perl, cluster-computing, submission

I'm attempting to debug a HPC cluster.

**One problem**: submitting Perl scripts into a several hundred node Linux Suse cluster via Open Grid Scheduler (OGS/GE 2011.11).

This generates a runtime error for Perl scripts on the "long queue" in the cluster, but not on the "short queue".

```
$> qsub -cwd -q short.q ./test.pl
```

Output is ok

```
$> qsub -cwd -q long.q ./test.pl
```

Output error log,
**/var/spool/sge/comp26/job_scripts/3141815: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `my'
/var/spool/sge/comp26/job_scripts/3141815: line 2:`open (my $fh, '>', 'test.out');'**

If I submit a shell script to the long queue it works, containing

```
perl ./test.pl
```

Any ideas?

System: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2), Perl v5.16.3 (yuk)

**Test script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Also tried #!/bin/perl
system("perl -v > perl.out");
open (my $fh, '>', 'test.out');
print $fh 'test';
close $fh;
```

Comment: That error message comes from the shell, not perl, so for whatever reason the script isn't being seen as a perl script

Comment: Thanks, I've asked it "which perl", but beyond that I'm stuck.

Comment: the recommended shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env perl` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791954/what-should-i-use-for-a-perl-scripts-shebang-line

Have you tried setting the exact path to your perl binary instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution,as @bytepusher described, was

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

and submission to `qsub -cwd -q long.q ./test.pl` was fine.